# Can a dense set $X$ in $\mathbb R$ contain a proper subset $A$ such that $A$ and $X-A$ are not dense in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, baire-category

Suppose $X$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ and $A\subset X$,then is it possible that $A$ and $X-A$ are both non-dense in $\mathbb R$.I think that at least one of them must be dense but I am having some problem to prove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about $X=\mathbb R, A=(0,1)$?